# CSS - how to center site for large screens (without bootstrap)

Tags: css

Maybe this has already been answered, but couldn't find the solution neither in Google, neither in Stackoverflow. Newbie here.

I use a large screen at home and rarely use the browser in fullscreen. But today i tried to see how a website i'm testing would look, and it's ugly. In normal size browser it's ok, but in a big screen it's all on the left.
How can i center it for large screens?

I know i could fill it and make things bigger for large screens, but i want to learn how to do this in case i need it.

Here is my HTML and CSS files

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
</head>


<header class="col-12">
  <!--logo-->
  <div class="col-3 logo">
    <img alt="logo" src="logo-lxfcl-new.png" width="210" height="54">
  </div>

  <div class="col-9 topMenu">
    <h4>Welcome</h4>
    <!--top menu-->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Annonces</li>
        <li>Comment faire</li>
        <li>contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<!--left menu-->
<nav class="col-3 sidemenu">
    <ul>
      <li>Ateliers</li>
      <li>Associations</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main class="col-9 sectionColor">
  <section>
    sdfsdefwef
  </section>
</main>

<!--footer-->
<footer class="col-12">
  copyright 
</footer>
```

```
/*defining the grid system*/
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%; max-width: 300px;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%; max-width: 900px;}
.col-9 {width: 75%; max-width: 900px;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%; max-width: 1200px;}

[class*="col-"] {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px;
}

.row::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
/*-------------------------------------*/

header, aside, footer, main, nav, section {
display: block;
}
/*---------------------------------------------*/



body {
font-family: roboto;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 150%;
background-color: #dddddd;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
float:left;
}

.logo img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.topMenu {
float:left;
clear: right;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.topMenu nav,
.topMenu h4 {
padding: 0;
}

.topMenu li {
display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #5e2f2f;
 padding-right: 30px;
 }



 .sidemenu li {
 border-bottom: dotted 1px #5e2f2f;
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height: 200%;
 color: #72a1e7;
 margin-left: -40px; /*this is because of the default webkit-padding*/
 max-width: 300px;
 }



nav {
 clear: left;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}



.sectionColor {
background-color: white;
}



footer {
clear: both;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 20px;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Comment: So, you don't want bootstrap but you're trying to replicate bootstrap? . . . What?!

Comment: i'm learning, and i don't want to call an external library or framework. I want to do it all so i can learn and understand what i'm doing. Later, i'll use it.

Comment: That makes sense. Re-implementing bits and pieces of the framework to understand why they do that. You should also read the documentation and the comments on the code. Those will help too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap your whole page in a `.wrapper` class, give `.wrapper` max-width value in px - for example 1200px, and then center it with: `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: so i should add that class in body element?

Comment: @fields probably better to add it as a div inside the body incase you need the full width body in future

Answer (score 1):

I would use newest centering CSS invention which is 
[FLEXBOX](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) Try applying the following code

---

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;}
```

In comparison to older CSS centering methods is effortless.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to introduce a wrapper to wrap all of the content on the site, make the width match the widest width you have in your columns (`.col-12` - and you can remove that width on `.col-12` now), and use `margin: auto;` to center it horizontally.

```css
/*defining the grid system*/
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%; max-width: 300px;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%; max-width: 900px;}
.col-9 {width: 75%; max-width: 900px;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

[class*="col-"] {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px;
}

.row::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
/*-------------------------------------*/

header, aside, footer, main, nav, section {
display: block;
}
/*---------------------------------------------*/



body {
font-family: roboto;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 150%;
background-color: #dddddd;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
float:left;
}

.logo img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.topMenu {
float:left;
clear: right;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.topMenu nav,
.topMenu h4 {
padding: 0;
}

.topMenu li {
display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #5e2f2f;
 padding-right: 30px;
 }



 .sidemenu li {
 border-bottom: dotted 1px #5e2f2f;
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height: 200%;
 color: #72a1e7;
 margin-left: -40px; /*this is because of the default webkit-padding*/
 max-width: 300px;
 }



nav {
 clear: left;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}



.sectionColor {
background-color: white;
}



footer {
clear: both;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 20px;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
</head>

<div class="wrap">

<header class="col-12">
  <!--logo-->
  <div class="col-3 logo">
    <img alt="logo" src="logo-lxfcl-new.png" width="210" height="54">
  </div>

  <div class="col-9 topMenu">
    <h4>Welcome</h4>
    <!--top menu-->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Annonces</li>
        <li>Comment faire</li>
        <li>contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<!--left menu-->
<nav class="col-3 sidemenu">
    <ul>
      <li>Ateliers</li>
      <li>Associations</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main class="col-9 sectionColor">
  <section>
    sdfsdefwef
  </section>
</main>

<!--footer-->
<footer class="col-12">
  copyright 
</footer>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing the `body` element. When you fix this, you can style your body as:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center only horizontally do as Plenarto said, wrap it in some `<div>` with `width` or `max-width` set in CSS and `margin: 0 auto`.

If you need to center everything vertically too, you need to place it in a table cell or something styled like a table cell. I use following trick in such cases:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100% }
html { display: table }
body { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle }
```